# Wine stopped working. How do I re-install w/o losing data

Tags: wine, winetricks

Wine has mysteriously stopped working. I have decided to simple entirely remove and re-install wine, but before I do this I want to make sure that I will not loose any of the multitudes of files and programs I have saved and installed on Wine in the past.

Can I just backup "drive_c" and "dosdevices" inside the .wine foider, then entirely remove the .wine directory (rm -rf ~/.wine), install wine again, and then just plop the backed-up folders back in the directory? Would I be able to run the programs normally?

Also, since I am already writing this, I might as well add what I know about what went wrong with Wine.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04. Wine worked fine about a week ago, and mysteriously stopped working.

If I run winecfg.exe, the process runs (according to top command), but nothing appears on screen. It just takes up 100% of one of my CPUs. The same exact thing happens if I run Winetricks or try and run a .exe program in wine. A process appears in top, takes up CPU, but nothing happens.

If I run wine through terminal, the results are as follows:

```
user@computer:~/Downloads/SpaceEngine 0.97/system$ wine SpaceEngine.exe 
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
modify_ldt: Invalid argument
err:seh:raise_exception Exception frame is not in stack limits => unable to dispatch exception.
```

I tried updating wine, but that did nothing. So might as well just wipe the install and start again. So how do I be sure I don't loose data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I don't know what went wrong - but I copy-pasted the whole .wine directory as a backup. Then I deleted the whole .wine directory, re-installed wine, and put back in ONLY the drive_c and dosdevices folders.

Works great now!

I don't know if either of those answers are relivant to my problem, or would have helped had I tried them - but what I did worked fine.

Just backup and re-install.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS x86_64 with 3.11.0-24-generic kernel, wine-1.7.18. 
I solved this issue by adding
`echo 1 > /proc/sys/abi/ldt16`
to 
`/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0` line. After reboot I can install win16 programs.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably trying to run a 16-bit Windows executable on a recently updated 64-bit Linux kernel.

Support for [16-bit segments was suspended](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/4/11/542) on 64-bit Linux systems because of a security issue.

This matter has recently been extensively [discussed on the WineHQ forum](http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=22540) and has been [reported as a bug](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36664).

At the moment, there is no fail proof workaround. You will have to wait for either a wine or kernel update.

Nonetheless, 32-bit Linux systems are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/abi/ldt16
```

and then start your application via wine. This temporarily enables 16bit support in the kernel.